# Python old version of Cython even when newer version installed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip, cython

I installed Cython 0.24.1 on my Raspberry Pi by doing this:

Pasted below is the command and terminal output.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade cython==0.24.1
Downloading/unpacking cython==0.24.1
  Downloading Cython-0.24.1.tar.gz (1.7MB): 1.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/setup.py) egg_info for package cython
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.

    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
Installing collected packages: cython
  Running setup.py install for cython
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c
    building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Plex/Scanners.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Actions.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Actions.c
    building 'Cython.Plex.Actions' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Actions.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Actions.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Plex/Actions.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Plex/Actions.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Lexicon.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Lexicon.c
    building 'Cython.Compiler.Lexicon' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Lexicon.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Lexicon.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Lexicon.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Compiler/Lexicon.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.c
    building 'Cython.Compiler.Scanning' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.c
    building 'Cython.Compiler.Parsing' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.c
    building 'Cython.Compiler.Visitor' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Compiler/Visitor.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.c
    building 'Cython.Compiler.FlowControl' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Compiler/FlowControl.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c
    building 'Cython.Compiler.Code' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Compiler/Code.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Compiler/Code.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.pyx to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.c
    building 'Cython.Runtime.refnanny' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Runtime/refnanny.cpython-34m.so
    cythoning /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.py to /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.c
    building 'Cython.Tempita._tempita' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c /tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/tmp/pip-build-hprgsgiw/cython/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.o -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.cpython-34m.so

    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
    Installing cygdb script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing cython script to /usr/local/bin
    Installing cythonize script to /usr/local/bin
Successfully installed cython
Cleaning up...
```

Looks like the installation has completed fine. But after this, if I do the following, it still return the old version. What am I missing?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -c "import cython;print(cython.__version__)"
0.21.1
```

Comment: What does `python3 -c "import cython; print(cython.__file__)"` return?

Comment: `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -c "import cython; print(cython.__file__)"
    

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cython.py`

Answer (score 1):

From the log, I can read `Installing cython script to /usr/local/bin`. I extrapolate that the library has installed in `/usr/local/python3something`. Two alternatives:

1. re-install using `pip3 install --user --upgrade cython==0.24.1` and make sure that `~/.local/bin` is in your [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).
2. add `/usr/local/bin` to your [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) and `/usr/local/python3something/site-packages` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Indeed, the `python3something` part must be changed to reflect the exact path on your system. Option "1" above should work even if my extrapolation is wrong.